# Activity doesn't work on adding a navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I have added two drawers- a navigation drawer from left, and a listview drawer from right. Earlier, my activity was working fine but now, my drawers are working fine, but, my activity has become totally unresponsive. (I have buttons in my activity which are now not working). My navigation drawer don't work on click of the (three line) button, but only when I slide.

I have this code in my activity pertaining to my drawers. I can provide the layout files if required. The other codein activity is not related to this.

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        // Handle the actions accordingly for all menus
        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        setContentView(R.layout.nav_layout);
        Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        DrawerLayout drawer2=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout2);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawer,toolbar,R.string.OPEN_DRAWER,R.string.CLOSE_DRAWER);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle2=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawer2,toolbar,R.string.OPEN_DRAWER2,R.string.CLOSE_DRAWER2);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        drawer2.addDrawerListener(toggle2);
        toggle.syncState();
        toggle2.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView=(NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        mDrawerList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);//this is actually right drawer
        CustomAdapter adapter=new CustomAdapter(this,R.layout.listview_item,mQuestionBank);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

}
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        DrawerLayout drawer=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        DrawerLayout drawer2=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout2);
        if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
        {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
        if(drawer2.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END))
        {
            drawer2.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }
```

I don't know if I have to override some other methods for things to work. In that case, let me know..
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do wonder why my question has not been answered or at least a suggestion...

Comment: Please upload xml file